# Assertion failed (!ssize.empty()) in remapBilinear

Tags: c++, opencv, camera-calibration

My `opencv_version` is: `4.1.0-pre`

I have follow code:

```
FileStorage fs("camera.yml", FileStorage::READ);
Mat cameraMatrix;
Mat distCoeffs;
fs["camera_matrix"] >> cameraMatrix;
fs["distortion_coefficients"] >> distCoeffs;
fs.release();

Mat image;
string fileName = "view000.bmp";
image = imread(fileName, IMREAD_COLOR);   // Read the file

Mat temp = image.clone();
undistort(temp, image, cameraMatrix, distCoeffs);

Size imageSize = image.size();
Mat view, rview, map1, map2;
initUndistortRectifyMap(cameraMatrix, distCoeffs, Mat(),
                    getOptimalNewCameraMatrix(cameraMatrix, distCoeffs, imageSize, 1, imageSize, 0),
                    imageSize, CV_16SC2, map1, map2);

remap(view, rview, map1, map2, INTER_LINEAR);
```

`undistort` function works properly, how ever first call to `remap` yields exception:

> OpenCV(4.1.0-pre) Error: Assertion failed (!ssize.empty()) in
>   remapBilinear, file /home/olga/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/imgwarp.cpp,
>   line 666

Here is `calibration_matrix` and `distortion_coefficients` from `camera.yml`:

```
camera_matrix: !!opencv-matrix
   rows: 3
   cols: 3
   dt: d
   data: [ 6.6979083645491733e+02, 0., 3.5720142378760517e+02, 0.,
       6.6818397497437070e+02, 2.2958328379477018e+02, 0., 0., 1. ]
distortion_coefficients: !!opencv-matrix
   rows: 5
   cols: 1
   dt: d
   data: [ -9.1630887760709781e-02, 6.3870694676062587e-02,
       -2.9224237615839681e-04, 8.0315318960669040e-04, 0. ]
```

Comment: where do you fill `view`? Calling the function with an empty source image doesn't make much sense

Comment: A! It is bug here! ) You are right. If you want, put it as answer, I will check it as right answer )

Comment: alright, not sure why you would use both `undistort` and `remap`, since you're doing the same with both

Comment: I just try to test if it actually the same. If it is the same, I will use undistort, since it is less code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were trying to apply the image remapping to an empty image.

The parameters are

```
remap(src, dst, mapx, mapy);
```

Your input `view` was an empty mat.

The most relevant image would probably be your input image, so

```
remap(temp , rview, map1, map2, INTER_LINEAR);
```